# Reinstall Mac OS X Snow Leopard after installing Linux

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro, and then decided to reinstall Snow Leopard. I inserted the SL install DVD, powered on holding the C key, but the Mac froze on the Apple logo.

I restarted holding the Option key, selected the Mac OS install disk, and then again, it froze on the Apple logo.

I booted another Mac, created a bootable USB install disk from the SL install DVD, powered on the frozen Mac with the USB stick in it holding the Option key, selected the Mac OS install disk (USB), and again, it froze on the Apple logo.

I tried to reset the PRAM, without success.
Ubuntu is still working fine.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: How do you know it froze? I recently needed to wait 15 minutes or so until the installer popped up when booting from DVD.

Comment: Wasn't that patient actually. I left it for maybe 5 to 10 minutes, I'll try a bit longer!

Comment: 30 minutes later, and still no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally bought [Mac OS X Lion](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/os-x-lion/id444303913?mt=12) on the App Store, and followed [these instructions](http://www.macworld.com/article/161069/2011/07/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html) to create a bootable DVD out of it.

This DVD worked like a charm!

Comment: Remember to accept this answer, or just delete the question. Looks like a broken SL DVD more than anything else.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer yet (24 hours remaining). I'm not sure about the broken DVD: it mounts fine in a running OS, and is copied with no error to a USB drive. I read some forum posts about similar problems with SL DVDs older than the version with which the laptop originally came, that might be my problem!

Comment: SL DVDs that came with a different Mac are almost guaranteed to not work. DVDs older than your Mac might also not work, that's true.

Comment: The DVD I was trying to boot from came straight from the Apple Store, not from a different Mac.